# iOS swift tableview.reloadData() not working after many attempts

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

//****EDITED******

Here is my viewDidLoad Method----->

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    addSlideMenuButton()


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(refreshOrders),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refreshedAvailableOrders"),
                                           object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(removedAnOrder),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "removedAvailableOrder"),
                                           object: nil)



    let _ordersManager:OrdersManager = OrdersManager.sharedInstance()


    /* Remove the title so that only a back arrow shows */
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    if(_ordersManager.getAvailableLoads() != nil){
        var objects = _ordersManager.getAvailableLoads() as? NSArray


        for (obj) in objects! {
            if let myOrder = obj as? Order{
                var i:Int = 0
                var length:Int = orders.count
                var foundOrder:Bool = false
                while(i<length){

                    if myOrder.OrderLegDistance == nil{
                        myOrder.OrderLegDistance = "--"
                    }

                    if let existingOrder = orders[i] as? order{
                        if(existingOrder.orderId ==  "\(myOrder.OrderId!)"){
                            let loadsDeliveredInt:Int? = Int(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)
                            let loadCountInt:Int? = Int(myOrder.LoadCount!)
                            var thisLoadsRemaining = loadCountInt! - loadsDeliveredInt!
                            orders[i] = order(dispatchNumber: "\(myOrder.DispatchNumber!)",orderId: "\(myOrder.OrderId!)", source: myOrder.SourceName! , sourceAddress1: myOrder.SourceAddress! , sourceAddress2: myOrder.SourceCity! + ", " + myOrder.SourceState! + " " + myOrder.SourceZip! , destination: myOrder.DestinationName!, destinationAddress1:myOrder.DestinationAddress!, destinationAddress2: myOrder.DestinationCity! + ", " + myOrder.DestinationState! + " " + myOrder.DestinationZip! , loads: "\(myOrder.LoadCount!)", loadsDelivered: "\(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)",  tons: "\(myOrder.TonsCount!)", price: "\(myOrder.PayRate!)", sourceDistance: myOrder.DistanceToSource!, onewayDistance: myOrder.OrderLegDistance!,  pickupStart: myOrder.PickupBy!, earliestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverStart!,latestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverBy!,product: myOrder.ProductName! , loadsRemaining: "\(thisLoadsRemaining)", truckType: myOrder.TruckType!, notes: myOrder.Notes!, isStarted: myOrder.IsStarted, isOnHold: myOrder.IsOnHold, payRateType: "\(myOrder.PayRateType!)", isStayOn: myOrder.IsStayOn, customerName: myOrder.CustomerName! )

                            foundOrder = true
                        }
                    }
                    i += 1
                }

                if(!foundOrder){


                    if myOrder.OrderLegDistance == nil{
                        myOrder.OrderLegDistance = "--"
                    }

                    let loadsDeliveredInt:Int? = Int(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)
                    let loadCountInt:Int? = Int(myOrder.LoadCount!)
                    var thisLoadsRemaining = loadCountInt! - loadsDeliveredInt!
                    orders.append(order(dispatchNumber: "\(myOrder.DispatchNumber!)",orderId: "\(myOrder.OrderId!)", source: myOrder.SourceName! , sourceAddress1: myOrder.SourceAddress! , sourceAddress2: myOrder.SourceCity! + ", " + myOrder.SourceState! + " " + myOrder.SourceZip! , destination: myOrder.DestinationName!, destinationAddress1:myOrder.DestinationAddress!, destinationAddress2: myOrder.DestinationCity! + ", " + myOrder.DestinationState! + " " + myOrder.DestinationZip! , loads: "\(myOrder.LoadCount!)", loadsDelivered: "\(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)",  tons: "\(myOrder.TonsCount!)", price: "\(myOrder.PayRate!)", sourceDistance: myOrder.DistanceToSource!, onewayDistance: myOrder.OrderLegDistance!,  pickupStart: myOrder.PickupBy!, earliestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverStart!,latestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverBy!,product: myOrder.ProductName! , loadsRemaining: "\(thisLoadsRemaining)", truckType: myOrder.TruckType!, notes: myOrder.Notes!, isStarted: myOrder.IsStarted, isOnHold: myOrder.IsOnHold, payRateType: "\(myOrder.PayRateType!)", isStayOn: myOrder.IsStayOn, customerName: myOrder.CustomerName! ))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(orders.count == 0){
        noOrdersView.isHidden = false
       // let config = GoVulcanConfig.sharedInstance()
        noOrdersLabel.text = "There Are No Open Orders Available For Pickup Near You"
    }
    else {
        noOrdersView.isHidden = true
    }



}
```

I call this method on a firebase update from the server and have tried everything

```
func refreshOrders(){

    let _ordersManager:OrdersManager = OrdersManager.sharedInstance()

    if(_ordersManager.getAvailableLoads() != nil){
        var objects = _ordersManager.getAvailableLoads() as? NSArray
        if(objects?.count == 0){
            orders.removeAll()
            noOrdersView.isHidden = false

            noOrdersLabel.text = "There Are No Open Orders Available For Pickup Near You"
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }else{
            noOrdersView.isHidden = true
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        for (obj) in objects! {
            if let myOrder = obj as? Order{
                var i:Int = 0
                var length:Int = orders.count
                var foundOrder:Bool = false
                while(i<length){
                    if myOrder.OrderLegDistance == nil{
                        myOrder.OrderLegDistance = "--"
                    }
                    if let existingOrder = orders[i] as? order{
                        if(existingOrder.orderId ==  "\(myOrder.OrderId!)"){
                            let loadsDeliveredInt:Int? = Int(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)
                            let loadCountInt:Int? = Int(myOrder.LoadCount!)
                            var thisLoadsRemaining = loadCountInt! - loadsDeliveredInt!
                            orders[i] = order(dispatchNumber: "\(myOrder.DispatchNumber!)",orderId: "\(myOrder.OrderId!)", source: myOrder.SourceName! , sourceAddress1: myOrder.SourceAddress! , sourceAddress2: myOrder.SourceCity! + ", " + myOrder.SourceState! + " " + myOrder.SourceZip! , destination: myOrder.DestinationName!, destinationAddress1:myOrder.DestinationAddress!, destinationAddress2: myOrder.DestinationCity! + ", " + myOrder.DestinationState! + " " + myOrder.DestinationZip! , loads: "\(myOrder.LoadCount!)", loadsDelivered: "\(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)",  tons: "\(myOrder.TonsCount!)", price: "\(myOrder.PayRate!)", sourceDistance: myOrder.DistanceToSource!, onewayDistance: myOrder.OrderLegDistance!,  pickupStart: myOrder.PickupBy!, earliestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverStart!,latestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverBy!,product: myOrder.ProductName! , loadsRemaining: "\(thisLoadsRemaining)", truckType: myOrder.TruckType!, notes: myOrder.Notes!, isStarted: myOrder.IsStarted, isOnHold: myOrder.IsOnHold, payRateType: "\(myOrder.PayRateType!)", isStayOn: myOrder.IsStayOn, customerName: myOrder.CustomerName! )
                            foundOrder = true
                        }
                    }
                    i += 1
                }

                if(!foundOrder){
                    if myOrder.OrderLegDistance == nil{
                        myOrder.OrderLegDistance = "--"
                    }
                    let loadsDeliveredInt:Int? = Int(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)
                    let loadCountInt:Int? = Int(myOrder.LoadCount!)
                    var thisLoadsRemaining = loadCountInt! - loadsDeliveredInt!
                    orders.append(order(dispatchNumber: "\(myOrder.DispatchNumber!)",orderId: "\(myOrder.OrderId!)", source: myOrder.SourceName! , sourceAddress1: myOrder.SourceAddress! , sourceAddress2: myOrder.SourceCity! + ", " + myOrder.SourceState! + " " + myOrder.SourceZip! , destination: myOrder.DestinationName!, destinationAddress1:myOrder.DestinationAddress!, destinationAddress2: myOrder.DestinationCity! + ", " + myOrder.DestinationState! + " " + myOrder.DestinationZip! , loads: "\(myOrder.LoadCount!)", loadsDelivered: "\(myOrder.LoadsDelivered!)",  tons: "\(myOrder.TonsCount!)", price: "\(myOrder.PayRate!)", sourceDistance: myOrder.DistanceToSource!, onewayDistance: myOrder.OrderLegDistance!,  pickupStart: myOrder.PickupBy!, earliestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverStart!,latestDelivery: myOrder.DeliverBy!,product: myOrder.ProductName! , loadsRemaining: "\(thisLoadsRemaining)", truckType: myOrder.TruckType!, notes: myOrder.Notes!, isStarted: myOrder.IsStarted, isOnHold: myOrder.IsOnHold, payRateType: "\(myOrder.PayRateType!)", isStayOn: myOrder.IsStayOn, customerName: myOrder.CustomerName! ))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I populate my cell

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      //use orders array to populate table cell

}
```

I am debugging someone else's code and It is horribly implemented. The code basically builds a orders array.

I am trying to refresh my tableview but it is not working. Any ideas why?

Comment: You call `self.myTableView.reloadData()` before populating `orders`? `self.myTableView.datasource` is set?

Comment: self.myTableView.datasource? I am new to swift and iOS can you help

Comment: Can I add self.myTableView.datasource = true?at the end of refresh orders? or at view didload?

Comment: I see that the orders array is being populated on viewdidload and later on refresh orders it s being populated again from api call again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see quite a few things wrong with the code, but a few things that may be related to your refresh issue:
(I presume the numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt use the orders property)

- Can you check via printout or breakpoint that the numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt are invoked after the orders array is populated?
- Can you check that the table view data source is set to this current class?
- If any other thing fails, I suggest you try to set some hard coded values in the tableView just to see that it's working as an UI component, then fix up the orders management and make sure a reload data is called after the array is available.

Good luck :)

Comment: Yes they are invoked when the view loads first. Also If I add an order at database the firebase update happens and the view gets a new record. Only when I remove the record the API call should remove the record

Comment: Try adding a self.myTableView.reloadData() after the for loop, I suspect the DispatchQueue.main.async blocks are not working

Comment: 1. When I add a record via api it gets added and screen gets refreshed. When I remove a record should it not go away. The block is getting hit and doing its job